# face detection using HAAR classifier

Tags: opencv

Iam working on face detection in openCV with HAAR classifier. Here is my code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <opencv2\objdetect\objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv\cv.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void detectAndDisplay(Mat frame);


String face_cascade_name = "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";

String eyes_cascade_name = "haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml";


CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
CascadeClassifier eye_cascade;



string window_name = "Capture- Face detection";



int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Mat frame = imread("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/lena.png");

    imshow("original picture", frame);

    if (face_cascade.load(face_cascade_name))
    {
        cout << "\n Error loading " << endl;
    }

    if (eye_cascade.load(eyes_cascade_name))
    {
        cout << "\n Error Loading " << endl;
    }

    if (!frame.empty())
    {
        detectAndDisplay(frame);
    }

    waitKey(0);


    return 0;
}

void detectAndDisplay(Mat frame)
{
    vector<Rect>faces;

    imshow("lena.png", frame);

    Mat frame_gray;

    cvtColor(frame, frame_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    equalizeHist(frame_gray, frame_gray);

    imshow("Gray Color Image", frame_gray);

    face_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0 | CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(20, 20));

    int k = faces.size();

    for (size_t i = 0; i <faces.size(); i++)
    {
        Point center(faces[i].x + faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].y + faces[i].height*0.5);

        ellipse(frame, center, Size(faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].height*0.5), 0, 0, 360, Scalar(255, 0, 0));

        Mat faceROI = frame_gray(faces[i]);

        vector<Rect>eyes;

        eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(faceROI, eyes, 1.1, 2, 0 | CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30));

        for (int j = 0; j < eyes.size(); j++)
        {
            Point center(faces[i].x + eyes[j].x + eyes[j].width*0.5, faces[i].y + eyes[j].y + eyes[j].height*0.5);
            int radius = cvRound((eyes[j].width + eyes[j].height)*0.25);
            circle(frame, center, radius, Scalar(0, 0,255), 4, 8, 0);

        }
    }
    imshow(window_name, frame);
}
```

Here My code is not working. face is not being detected. iam trying get int k=faces.size() which is getting '0' value. what could be the possible error.

Comment: You are trying to detect face of a koala. That's the error.

Comment: Even it is not working for lena.png also. that also I tried.

Comment: Try with several different images, not just one image, or image of an aminal... It is better to test it with a web cam..

Comment: check face_cascade.empy() . if so, your cascade-file was not found.

Comment: probably `if (face_cascade.load(face_cascade_name))` should return true if it was successful (but isnt documented), so you might use it wrong in your image and you should see your error message `cout << "\n Error loading " << endl;` if it was successful. Try to provide the full classifier xml absolute path to the string and try again.

Answer (score 1):

That is because your if-condition to load the cascade is not logic:

Yours is:

```
   if (face_cascade.load(face_cascade_name))
    {
        cout << "\n Error loading " << endl;
    }

    if (eye_cascade.load(eyes_cascade_name))
    {
        cout << "\n Error Loading " << endl;
    }
```

But it should be:

```
    if (!face_cascade.load(face_cascade_name))
    {
        cout << "\n Error loading " << endl;
    }

    if (!eye_cascade.load(eyes_cascade_name))
    {
        cout << "\n Error Loading " << endl;
    }
```

You forget the '!' in the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

`face_cascade.load(face_cascade_name)` obviously returns FALSE when classifier successfully loaded. You can find it in one of the samples provided with OpenCV library `facedetect.cpp`
This is why you don't see that the loading process failed and you provided wrong path to haarcascade file.